# WPF - expander dont hide

Tags: wpf, expander

Is it possible, do not allow to hide expander, when user clicks on header? I have custom style for expander. I've tried to set ToggleButton IsEnabled=false, but it would be better, when nothing happens on click.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "clicks on header", do you mean on the text of the header ? And what do you mean "it would be better, when nothing happens on click" ?

Answer (score 2):

An Expander *by definition* is collapsible; the visual associated with it is coincidental.  It sounds like what you want is not an expander, but a visual effect similar to the expander, but without the behaviour.

So, simply don't use an Expander.  If you want the visual appearance of the Expander without the behaviour, scrape the Xaml (using a tool like Blend) and reuse it, or restyle an existing control.